# How to write a correct setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I was trying to write a setup.py for a [small chat application](https://github.com/XuryaX/chatery/tree/snapcraft_integration) I created.

Here is the **setup.py** code:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from os import environ as env
import subprocess

from pip.req import parse_requirements

requirements = [str(req.req) for req in parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=False)]

try:
    VERSION = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'describe', '--tags']).strip()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    VERSION = '0.dev'

setup(
    name='chatery',
    version=VERSION,
    description="Lightweight Chat application"
                " - with Twitter Support",
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    author="Shaurya-Xoxzo",
    author_email='shauryadeepc@hotmail.com',
    url='http://www.xoxzo.com',
    license='MIT',
    install_requires=requirements,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'chatery = chatery:main',
        ],
    },
    zip_safe=False
)
```

I took reference from the [httpstat](https://github.com/reorx/httpstat/blob/master/setup.py) project which is small as well, but apparrently that works and my setup.py does not.

It isn't able to find the file that it is supposed to load. I get the following errors.
When I write chatery on console.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/chatery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('chatery==0.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'chatery')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named chatery
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I just cloned your project and installed it (python3.5) and it works fine.

Comment: `python setup.py install` worked? and then `chatery` ?

Answer (score 4):

I've just cloned your project and it has wrong folder structre - you should put files related to your application into another folder (e.g. `chatery`), not in the same one where other distribution-related files reside.
So instead of having this:

```
app.py
assets/
Caddyfile
constants.py
database/
dbutils/
install.sh
README.md
requirements.txt
run.sh
setup.py
tests/
utils.py
```

you should have something like this:

```
Caddyfile
chatery/
    app.py
    assets/
    constants.py
    database/
    dbutils/
    __init__.py
    utils.py
install.sh
README.md
requirements.txt
run.sh
setup.py
tests/
```

In your `setup.py` you need to slightly modify `entry-points`  argument to:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'chatery=chatery.app:main',
    ],
}
```

You also need to create `MANIFEST.in` file to include `assets` folder (you might want to add `database` folder as well if it's needed by your application):

```
recursive-include chatery/assets *
```

Now you can install and run your application:

```
~$ python setup.py install
   # many long lines
~$ chatery
[2017-08-19 14:43:21,994] INFO Using epoll
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:21] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:21] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:21] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:21] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:21] ENGINE Starting WebSocket processing
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:21] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:21] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:22] ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:9000
[19/Aug/2017:14:43:22] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

And when I enter `http://127.0.0.1:9000` in my browser, I get:
[image]